# mongoose model validation failed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm building a todo list app and keep facing this issue with mongoose model validation here's the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  complete: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Todo", TodoSchema);
```

while the post request

```
router.post("/new", async (req, res) => {
  const todo = new Todo({ description: req.body.description });

  try {
    const newTodo = await todo.save();
    res.status(201).json(newTodo);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

when sending a post request using rest client extension in VS code

```
POST http://localhost:3000/new

Content-Type: application/json 

{
    "description" : "get milk"
}
```

i get this error message back

```
{
  "message": "Todo validation failed: description: Path `description` is required."
}
```

Comment: You can try to pass explicit string value to the description. If it pass, it means is something wrong with the payload parsing. `const todo = new Todo({ description: 'test string' });`

Comment: It did pass guess it is a payload problem how would should i fix it?

Comment: maybe that: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/body but it is only guess. I can't read your application code from your mind :p

Comment: weird thing is up until a week ago i didn't get this error it worked just fine :/